# Match/Case not condition

Tags: switch-statement, python-3.10

How do I use a not in the new match/case structure?

```
a = 5
match a:
    case not 10:
        print(a)
```

This produces an error. How would I correctly syntax this?

Comment: Yes, the new pattern matching is great. However a simple `if a != 10:` fits here better

Comment: Yeah sorry this is just an example, I know that this is a terrible place to use a match/case haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use `not` in structural pattern matching, an alternative is to capture the values you need and then use the default `_` case to be the 'not' expression.

```
a = 5
match a:
    case 10:
        print(a)
    case _:
        print("not 10")
```

EDIT:
I was curious and did some research, turns out a negative match was rejected.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#negative-match-patterns

Comment: If anything, I'd prefer using a guard match instead of (potentially) `case 10: pass`

Answer (score 1):

The [PEP recommends](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/#negative-match-patterns) that negation could be implemented using guards. e.g.:

```
a = 5
match a:
    case x if x != 10:
        print(a)
```

Obviously in this simple case you could just use an `if` statement, but as you say, this is a toy example, but this may be useful for a more complex use case.